# SonarQube Single Sign On Plugin, update groups from HttpServletRequest

Tags: ruby, sonarqube

I am writing a single sign on plugin for SonarQube.
All my user information are located in the UserPrincipal of the HttpRequest (not the password ;-) ).
For the moment, I can sign on and provide the UserDetails to Sonar through the method

```
public UserDetails doGetUserDetails(Context context);
```

Now I would like to provide the groups of the user to SonarQube but the method

```
public Collection<String> doGetGroups(String username)
```

does not provide the context.

To solve my issue, I have modified the code of need_authentication.rb of Sonar (located in sonarqube-4.4\web\WEB-INF\lib)
to call a method

```
public Collection<String> doGetGroups(String username, HttpServletRequest)
```

I have written.

But I don't like modyfing source code; I would prefer overide it by extending the class PluginRealm of the file need_authentication.rb.

Basically, how do I extend a class in SonarQube ?
I know how to overide a controller but not class located in lib folder.
Also (I don't know Ruby at all).

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5430? Because we're about to add it in SonarQube as a native feature.

Comment: Thank you Fabrice for your answer.
The authentication feature seems great, but will it allow to pass the SonarQube groups as parameters in the header ?
Basically, I don't want to manage user membership to a group on Sonar side but on my SSO platform side.
that's why I want ot use the groups definition already located in the Principal of the HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Hopefully this will be possible, yes.

Answer (score 1):

[SONAR-5430](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5430) will allow to natively implement such a feature.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I just need to wait. Look forward to using this feature

Answer (score 0):

For people who cannot use the solution of Fabrice, here is what I did until the new feature is released.

I create a controller in ruby I add to my plugin realm.
This controller extends ApplicationController controller.

It redefines authenticate method wich calls the default method of Sonar

```
    def authenticate
    begin
      self.current_user = User.authenticate(nil, nil, servlet_request)

    if self.current_user
        my_synchronize_groups(servlet_request)
    end

    rescue Exception => e
      self.current_user = nil
      Rails.logger.error(e.message)
    end
    redirect_back_or_default(home_url)
  end
```

When you use a `User.authenticate(nil, nil, servlet_request)` it calls the `synchronize_groups(user)` in need_authorization.rb and synchronize the groups.

What I do is calling my_synchronize_groups after User.authenticate(nil, nil, servlet_request) to override the groups synchronization done by sonar.

Here is the code of my_synchronize_groups

```
def my_synchronize_groups(servlet_request)
Rails.logger.debug("My synchronize_groups method")
myRealm = RealmFactory.realm
Rails.logger.debug("My realm  #{myRealm}")
    if myRealm
        myGroupsProvider = myRealm.instance_variable_get(:@java_groups_provider)
        Rails.logger.debug("My group provider #{myGroupsProvider}")

        if myGroupsProvider
          begin
            groups = myGroupsProvider.doGetGroups(servlet_request)
          rescue Exception => e
            Rails.logger.error("Error from my groups provider: #{e.message}")
          else
            if groups
              self.current_user.groups = []
              for group_name in groups
                group = Group.find_by_name(group_name)
                if group
                  self.current_user.groups << group
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
    end
end
```

The method myGroupsProvider.doGetGroups(servlet_request) is a method located in  MyGroupsProvider.java which extends ExternalGroupsProvider.java and return a collection of String.

I am not saying it is the best solution but with my knowledge of Ruby ...

Hoping it can help

Simon